# How to combine a MappedSuperclass behaviour and declaring the class as Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, hierarchy

Is there a way to have a class being declared as a @MappedSuperclass, e.g. in order to inherit common properties AND in parallel have that class being able to be referenced as an object property in other classes?

Little more background information:

I have a class with some properties that all extending classes should have, let's say for example

```
class Resource {
   String id;
   String description;
   String value;
}
```

This would be a use case for @MappedSuperclass. All extending classes/types would inherit from that class.

But I also have an other class, e.g.

```
@Entity
class MyList extends Resource {
   Resource firstElement;
   MyList otherElements;
}
```

So, here, I would not be able to have that object property `firstElement` of type Resource, because Resource is not an @Entity.

Is this possible? What would you recommend to do?

Some things I have thought about in this context:

- I would like to use JOINED inheritance, since this allows me to have a very nice and clean schema on database level. I have one table for each class and subclass and nice foreign key references. Drawback here of course is that there are more joins when querying objects, but thats ok.
- I don't want to use TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance, because I have a bunch of data model classes and also a class level hierarchy of 3 in average. Using TABLE_PER_CLASS would mean to have database tables with a huge amount of columns.
- When I let `Resource` be an @Entity and I query the database for let's say `Resource.value` this would result in a join over a huge amount of tables. In my data model about 50-60 tables.

Have you encountered such a design issue? How did you balance between a clean database design and performance? Many people recommend the TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance hierarchy (haven't tried it yet), although I can't image having like all the properties of all classes in one table...

Comment: Do you want to be able to reference all the entities extending Resource in MyList, or only some of them? What are you trying to achieve, at a higher-level?

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, but maybe this is not the best example. It should just show that another class has an object property that is of type `Resource`, thus of the type that should function as a 'super class' for all other classes. I think this is not possible when this class is annotated with @MappedSuperclass.

Comment: No, it's not indeed. If you told us what you want to achieve, at a higher level, maybe we could find another, better solution.